# Receiving file content via API without post keys in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, post, parameters

I'm currently receiving a file using `file[content]=%FILECONTENTHERE%`. I'd like to receive my file directly, without `file[content]` or any kind of POST keys.

I'm currently doing something like this in my controller:

```
def file_from_params
  return nil if params[:file].blank? || params[:file][:content].blank?
  temp = Tempfile.new(['import', '.txt'])
  temp.write params[:file][:content]
  temp.rewind
  temp
end
```

How can I achieve this in Rails?

Answer (score 1):

Solved using `request.body.read`:

```
def file_from_params
  file = request.body.read
  return nil if file.blank?
  temp = Tempfile.new(['import', '.txt'])
  temp.write file
  temp.rewind
  temp
end
```